# Woocommerce to show other category after all product in current one

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, categories, product

Is there a plugin or some code that after opening some category and all products are show to show products from other category. Because some category or sub-category have only 2-4 products and I want to fill the page with other category product similar.

Example: Gloves

Glove page title

2-4 products

And then some category Boots with 5-6 products

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this may simply be to create multiple categories - eg an "apparel" category and assign it both gloves *and* boots. The more complicated way might be to use the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to generate a listing.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'my-glove-category'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'my-boots-category'
        )
    )
);

$executedQuery = new WP_Query($args);
if ($executedQuery->have_posts()) {
    while ($executedQuery->have_posts()) {
        $executedQuery->the_post(); //increment the post pointer, getting us the next post in the list
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No products were found.';
}
```

This example will grab every product that is either in `my-glove-category` or `my-boots-category`. If you want to sort by the category, that starts to become a bit tougher.

You can also use `product_tag` as a taxonomy for these queries, see [the installed taxonomies and post types for WooCommerce.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/)